# How to make Firefox treat forward and back slashes the same in url or file-paths?

Tags: url, firefox

Is there a way to make Firefox treat / like \ and vice versa in the url or local file path (rewrite it)?  Through a tweak, add-on, or anything?

- this is related to some local pages and links in some files.

*P.S. That behavior is already in IE and Chrome.*

Comment: Can you provide a URL example ?

Comment: d:/folder1/folder2/1.html    -  I don't want to have to change the path to \ instead of / for each page I open

Comment: well i tried the URL `D:\MEDIA` in FF and it automatically changed to `file:///D:/MEDIA/` so it seems to work in FF as well

Comment: yes, but more than one subfolder won't work.. like d:\media/folder/file - the other / will not make the link work..  and I don't type the address..  I just click on it and need it to work

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should NEVER user backslashes in a URL. Backslahes are not url safe - and although most browsers are somewhat relaxed with them, it can cause problems at many points of the url interpretation.

To ensure you don't have to do that, Windows browsers should be able to understand forward slashes in this context.

Like:

```
file:///C|/W95/Calc.exe
```

I heard there is an Addon calles Slashy that may do what you want. I have not tried it, just threw it into Google.

Comment: I won't use them on my website, just for local files..  and the behavior is already in IE and Chrome

Comment: Sorry: That doesn't make it any better.

Answer (score 0):

here's something that might help you:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
    function onload() {
        var list=document.getElementsByTagName("A");
        for(i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
        {
            if (list[i].href != null && list[i].href.length > 2 && list[i].href.substring(2,1) == ":") {
                list[i].href = "file:///"+list[i].href.replace(/\\/g, '\/');
            }
        }   
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="onload();">
    <a href="D:\Perso\gwt/eclipse"> hey you </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Tested on IE, Chrome, Safari and FF

Comment: I am sorry, how can this script be implemented or added as a new behavior to Firefox so any page that has that url or filepath on local computer be changed?

Comment: i thought the URLs are inside a page and you needed to make all of them point to the right path. Now if you type or copy paste the URL directly in the adress bar then sorry i miss understood your question.

Comment: thanks for your time..  the matter is related to may links and paths.. that's why I want Firefox to read it normally as IE and Chrome..